# Streaming a video to multiple end users with node.js and ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, pipe, video-streaming

I'm designed an API endpoint with node.js and express which will accept a url from a different part of the application, convert it into a webm stream, and allow multiple different end users to receive the end result without too much backend processing.

I'd like to have the process running once and pipe the resulting stream to n endpoint calls without using temp files to hold it. So far, all of my attempts to store the output in a temporary object have failed.

What would be the best method of going about doing this?

The following does not work, but is an example of what I've been trying to do.

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import FfmpegCommand from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import stream from 'stream';

const app = express();
const port = 3002;
const activeStreams = {};

app.use(cors());

app.get('/video/stream', (req, res) => {

  var streamUrl = new URL(req.query.streamurl);
  var protocol = streamUrl.protocol;

  if (activeStreams[streamUrl] === undefined) {
    activeStreams[streamUrl] = new stream.Duplex();
    if (['udp:', 'rtmp:', 'rtsp:'].includes(protocol)) {
      FfmpegCommand(path)
      .toFormat('webm')
      .on('error', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
          console.log('an error occurred', err.message);
          console.log("stdout:\n" + stdout);
          console.log("stderr:\n" + stderr);
      })
      .pipe(activeStreams[streamUrl], {end: true});
    }
    activeStreams[streamUrl].read().pipe(res);
  } else {
    activeStreams[streamUrl].read().pipe(res);   
  }
});
```